# "Select query equivalent" in R to select from one data frame and paste values to the second frame accordingly

Tags: r, select, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames:

```
temp <- data.frame(
  team1 = c("Chennai Super Kings","Deccan Chargers","Delhi Daredevils"),
  team2 = c("Mumbai Indians","Royal Challengers Bangalore","Gujarat Lions")
)

teamdata <- data.frame(
  teamname=c("Chennai Super Kings","Deccan Chargers","Delhi Daredevils",
             "Mumbai Indians","Royal Challengers Bangalore","Gujarat Lions"),
  matchesplayed = c("100","200","300","400","500","600"),
  matcheswon = c("50","100","150","200","250","300")
)
```

In the *temp* data frame I want to add variables such as *team1matchesplayed* and *team2matchesplayed* or *team1matcheswon* and *team2matcheswon* according to the name of the team in variables *team1* and *team2* of the *temp* dataframe. The values should be populated from *teamdata* data frame. New columns should be generated in the *temp* data frame.

P.S: This is my first question on here and may not be the best representation. Apologies: Sorry for attaching images earlier. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, you can use `dput(your_data)`

Comment: Example code given to run. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Simply `merge` twice on both *team1* and *team2* respectively:

```
# NESTED MERGE
mdf <- merge(merge(temp, teamdata, by.x=c("team1"), by.y=c("teamname"), all.x=TRUE),
             teamdata, by.x=c("team2"), by.y=c("teamname"), all.x=TRUE)

# RENAME COLUMNS
mdf <- setNames(mdf, c("team2", "team1", "team1_matchesplayed", "team1_matcheswon", 
                       "team2_matchesplayed", "team2_matcheswon"))

# REORDER COLUMNS
mdf <- mdf[c("team1", "team2", "team1_matchesplayed", "team2_matchesplayed", 
             "team1_matcheswon", "team2_matcheswon")]
mdf

#                 team1                       team2 team1_matchesplayed team2_matchesplayed team1_matcheswon team2_matcheswon
# 1    Delhi Daredevils               Gujarat Lions                 300                 600              150              300
# 2 Chennai Super Kings              Mumbai Indians                 100                 400               50              200
# 3     Deccan Chargers Royal Challengers Bangalore                 200                 500              100              250
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(sqldf)
Loading required package: gsubfn
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: RSQLite

> temp2=sqldf("select temp.*,matchesplayed as team1matchesplayed,matcheswon as team1matcheswon from temp,teamdata where temp.team1=teamdata.teamname")
> temp2
                team1                       team2 team1matchesplayed
1 Chennai Super Kings              Mumbai Indians                100
2     Deccan Chargers Royal Challengers Bangalore                200
3    Delhi Daredevils               Gujarat Lions                300
  team1matcheswon
1              50
2             100
3             150
> temp3=sqldf("select temp2.*,matchesplayed as team2matchesplayed,matcheswon as team2matcheswon from temp2,teamdata where temp2.team2=teamdata.teamname")
> temp3
                team1                       team2 team1matchesplayed
1 Chennai Super Kings              Mumbai Indians                100
2     Deccan Chargers Royal Challengers Bangalore                200
3    Delhi Daredevils               Gujarat Lions                300
  team1matcheswon team2matchesplayed team2matcheswon
1              50                400             200
2             100                500             250
3             150                600             300
```

Comment: Why not use explicit joins with `JOIN` introduced as the SQL standard 25 years ago? Here you use implicit joins with `WHERE`. Though equivalent performance, latter is harder to read. In fact with `JOIN` you can combine both queries into one!